# Disable one item of the radio button in gWidgets

Tags: r, user-interface, gtk, gwidgets, gui-toolkit

Is it possible to disable the particular item that selected in the radio button? Below is my example code:

```
ts <- c("a", "b", "c")
myRadio <- gradio(ts, container = window)

#Disable the entire radio button
enabled(myRadio) <- FALSE
```

My question is, What if I only want to disable only the first item - "a". Is it possible to do this is gwidgets?

Comment: Not by design. You can change the items to select from with [<- though.

Comment: Well, i changed it with check box instead of radio button. thanks for your reply.

Comment: @jverzani I'm also interested in doing something similar. How difficult would it be to add such functionality to `gWidgets2`?

Comment: It is a pretty non-standard interface. I don't think I'd add it to gWidgets2, but could cook up some Gtk-specific hack if you wanted.